# Error in getting Date input form user and storing in database using JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, derby

I am developing a web application based on JSF technology. I use Eclipse as the IDE and using Apache Derby as a database.

When getting user input, I have one of the fields as a date field, i.e, Date of Birth.
But when I update the database table, I get error report.

```
 Date Of Birth:
 <h:inputText value="#{employeeBean.dob}">
 <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
 </h:inputText>
```

Since the derby database accepts date in the format yyyy-mm-dd, I give input in the same way and have also used the same format.

This is the error I get.

```
 Exception while setting value for expression : #{employeeBean.dob} of component with 
 path : {Component-Path : [Class:javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /homepage.jsp]
 [Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: j_id_jsp_996426310_1]
 [Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText,Id: j_id_jsp_996426310_6]}

 Caused by:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Cannot convert 1/8/87 5:39 AM of type class
 java.util.Date to class java.sql.Date
```

Some one help me with this.

Comment: Apart from the problem, your `yyyy-mm-dd` pattern is wrong. It's now saying `year-minute-day`. You want `year-Month-day`. Learn here about the right patterns: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: ya, you were right.. And error identified by Bozho was also the reason for the problem. After changing both, got the answer. thanks to both of u..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSF uses `java.util.Date` and derby perhaps expects `java.sql.Date`, you have to do something in order to acoomodate this gap:

- change the type of the managed bean property to `java.util.Date`
- if doing only the above doesn't work, convert between the two before saving. This can be done with the following constructor (Note that I don't know how you are going to persist the object to the database, so I'm guessing)

  ```
  java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(jsfProvidedDate.getTime());
  ```

Comment: Correct, that was the problem and I had the pattern also wrong as suggested by BalusC. I changed the type to java.util.Date, stored the variable in a string with the desired pattern and stored in the database. :-) Thank you.